# В поисках Java Mail API - подписчика на обновления с сервера

Tags: java, email, imap

Задача следующая: написать сервис, который будет слушать состояние mail сервера по IMAP и получать информацию об обновлении на сервере.

Разумеется, что помощью javamail api я могу делать запрос, получать информацию, сравнивать с предыдущим стейтом, делать это в бесконечном цикле по таймеру, но моя цель не хранить стейт, а только получать информацию о новых письмах и как-то их обрабатывать.

Примерно так:

setHandler((mail)-> mail.getSubject() );

Т.е. прописать callback (например, дополнительно настроив фильтры на письма - получать callback от определенных отправителей) и все.

Собственно, такое API можно написать самому, но ведь в Java есть все :)))

Может кто-нибудь посоветует, есть ли готовая либа?

Comment: [IdleManager](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IdleManager.html) - не то?

Comment: @zRrr Да, то что нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: Если заработает, напишите ответ, пожалуйста